# Navigation panel button clicked and update other panel

Tags: php, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap

My `bootstrap` site has side panel and main panel.
[image]

Main panel has paragraphs about several countries which comes from MySQL database(works fine). I want make as when i select country from side panel select menu, update main panel according to the relevant country. What is the best way to do this task?

```
<div><li>
  <label class="label label-custom">Country</label>
   <select class="btn country-select-custom">
     <option value="any" selected>Any</option>
     <option value="usa">USA</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
     <option value="india">India</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>                    
 </li></div><div>
<?php
    foreach ($value as $add) {
        echo "<div'>";
        echo '<p class="target" news_country = "' . $add->country . '" >' . $add->newsdata . '</p>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?></div>
```

Comment: use jquery and id from the first column, pass value to php, and return back to second column values based upon that id

Comment: Agreeing with @MuhammedM.- here is a link https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ you pass the parameter to the jquery and then output html or json as your response which you display in the main panel.